# How can I realize a APIView to get my requirement data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class TypeModel(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Amodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    type = models.ForeignModel(to=TypeModel)
    in_use = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

the Amodel is the main model, it has a `type` field refer to TypeModel.

in the `serializers.py`:

```
class AmodelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Amodel
        fields = "__all__"


class TypeModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TypeModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

My requirement is fetch the Amodel data like this, it should be divided by `type`, I want to get this type data:

```
[
  {
    "type": {
      name: 'type1' 
    },
   "count": {
      "used": 12,  # the in_use is `True`
      "unused": 24
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

---

Calculate the used and unused count.

```
    for amodel in amodel_qs:
        if amodel.in_use: used_count+=1 
        else: unused_count +=1
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of **`count`** field here, in your **response**?

Comment: Where do you get **`used_count`**  and **`unused_count`** ?